# Is it possible to return a PartialView or View depending on conditions inside your controllers method?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

Is there a way to redirect to a page even if my method is expecting a PartialView to be returned?

```
    public PartialViewResult PlacementConfirmed(int placementID)
    {

        if (placementID == 5)
        {
            // Redirect to ambiance View
            // ???


        }

        return PartialView("_PlacementConfirmed");
    }
```

Comment: Is this in the controller of your project?

Comment: Yes, it is in a controller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could return just an "ActionResult", PartialViewResult inherits from ViewResultBase, and ViewResultBase inherits from ActionResult.

So you could do something like this:

```
public ActionResult PlacementConfirmed(int placementID)
{

    if (placementID == 5)
        return View("View");

    return PartialView("_PlacementConfirmed");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If this's in the controller of your project you could do something like this:

```
       public PartialViewResult PlacementConfirmed(int placementID)
       {

          if (placementID == 5)
          {
            return RedirectToAction("redirectView");
          }

          return PartialView("_PlacementConfirmed");

       }
```